# Как перемешать строки в очень большом текстовом файле?

Tags: алгоритм, delphi, случайные-числа

Сделала вот такой код. Суть которого перемешивание строк в текстовом файле.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  s: TStringList;
  z, p, q: Integer;
begin
  s := TStringList.Create;
  s.LoadFromFile('C:\text.txt');
  z := 50;
  while (z > 0) do begin
    p := random(s.Count);
    q := random(s.Count);
    s.Exchange(p, q);
    dec(z);
  end;
  s.SaveToFile('c:\text.txt');
  s.Free;
end;
```

Переделываю под чтение построчно, что бы не загружать в память:
**Не могу понять как дописать перемешивание ?**

```
var
  z, p, q: Integer;
  ft, ft2: TextFile;
  s:string;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    AssignFile(ft, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(ft);
    AssignFile(ft2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\rez.txt');
    Rewrite(ft2); // чтобы создался новый, если нету, или перезаписался с нуля
    Append(ft2); // чтобы можно было добавлять строки, а не перезаписывать каждый раз
    begin
      while not eof(ft) do
      begin
        readln(ft,s);
        //////////////////////////////////////
        Вот тут помогите дописать перемешивание строк?
        //////////////////////////////////////
        writeln(ft2,s)
      end;
      closefile(ft);
      closefile(ft2);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм простой:

1. Создаем список пар <номер строки, длина строки>
2. Перемешиваем этот список
3. В этом списке заполняем еще один параметр - смещение строки в результирующем файле
4. Последовательно читаем файл, по индексу строки определяем, куда ее записать и записываем в результирующий файл

Реализация

```
uses
  System.Classes,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults;

type
  TLineInfo = record
    LineNum: Integer;
    Length: Integer;
  end;

procedure ReadLines(AList: TList<TLineInfo>; const AFileName: string);
var
  LStr: AnsiString;
  LFile: TextFile;
  LInfo: TLineInfo;
begin
  LInfo.LineNum := 0;
  AssignFile(LFile, AFileName);
  Reset(LFile);
  try
    while not Eof(LFile) do begin
      Readln(LFile, LStr);
      LInfo.Length := Length(LStr) + Length(sLineBreak);
      AList.Add(LInfo);
      Inc(LInfo.LineNum);
    end;
  finally
    Close(LFile);
  end;
end;

procedure ShuffileLines(AList: TList<TLineInfo>);
begin
  AList.Sort(TComparer<TLineInfo>.Construct(
    function (const AItem1, AItem2: TLineInfo): Integer
    begin
      Result := Random(3) - 1;
    end
  ))
end;

procedure MakeIndices(AList: TList<TLineInfo>; AIndices: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>);
var
  Li: Integer;
  LOffset: Integer;
  LInfo: TLineInfo;
begin
  LOffset := 0;
  for Li := AList.Count - 1 downto 0 do begin
    LInfo := AList[Li];
    AList.Delete(Li);
    AIndices.Add(LInfo.LineNum, LOffset);
    Inc(LOffset, LInfo.Length);
  end;
end;

procedure WriteLines(AIndices: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>; const AFileName: string);
const
  CRLF: AnsiString = sLineBreak;
var
  LStr: AnsiString;
  LSrcFile: TextFile;
  LDstFile: TStream;
  LIdx: Integer;
  LOffset: Integer;
begin
  LIdx := 0;
  AssignFile(LSrcFile, AFileName);
  Reset(LSrcFile);
  try
    LDstFile := TFileStream.Create(AFileName + '.new', fmCreate);
    try
      while not Eof(LSrcFile) do begin
        Readln(LSrcFile, LStr);
        LOffset := AIndices[LIdx];
        LDstFile.Position := LOffset;
        LDstFile.WriteBuffer(LStr[1], Length(LStr) * SizeOf(LStr[1]));
        LDstFile.WriteBuffer(CRLF[1], Length(CRLF) * SizeOf(CRLF[1]));
        Inc(LIdx);
      end;
    finally
      LDstFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Close(LSrcFile);
  end;
end;

procedure ShuffileFile(const AFileName: string);
var
  LList: TList<TLineInfo>;
  LIndices: TDictionary<Integer, Integer>;
begin
  LList := TList<TLineInfo>.Create;
  try
    // Считываем информацию о строках из файла
    ReadLines(LList, AFileName);
    // Перемешиваем информацию о строках
    ShuffileLines(LList);
    LIndices := TDictionary<Integer, Integer>.Create(LList.Count);
    try
      // Создаем индекс смещений
      MakeIndices(LList, LIndices);
      // Перемешиваем строки в файле
      WriteLines(LIndices, AFileName);
    finally
      LIndices.Free;
    end;
  finally
    LList.Free;
  end;
end;

if OpenDialog.Execute then
  ShuffileFile(OpenDialog.FileName);
```

Comment: Хорошая идея. Только я бы использовал вместо старого доброго AssignFile(f,filename)/readln(f,string)  TStreamReader с методом ReadLine - это быстрее, особенно на больших файлах.

Comment: Только как еще этот код прикрутить к кнопке через OpenDialog. То есть нажали на кнопку, открыли и обработали. P/S Может и вопрос глупый но что то я не могу сделать. Заранее благодарна.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov Честно говоря никогда с ним не работал

Comment: @Татьяна Добавил код с OpenDialog

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, Огромнейшее вам спасибо. Разобралась, работает.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы перемешивать строки, вам надо иметь к ним доступ. Учитывая, что вы не можете их загрузить все и сразу, стоит использовать некоторое "окно" - считывать, например по 5000 строк (или сколько влезает в память), перемешивать и сохранять, например 2000, удаляя их из загруженных. Затем прочитать 2000, чтобы опять было 5000, перемешать их и сохранить 2000 и так до конца файла. В конце - записать все оставшиеся.

Качество перемешивания будет не очень равномерным, но вам, может быть, подойдет.