# Перемешать строки Delphi (мои варианты)

Tags: delphi

Реализовала код который меняет строки местами в текстовом файле, перемешивает. Но проблема в том что на размерах в 250 мегабайт не работает. Сильно загружает память из за того что все грузиться в память.

Может кто подсказать как сделать по другому, что бы можно было работать с текстовыми файлами без загрузки в память.

```
var
sl: TStringList;
i, j: integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
sl := TStringList.Create;
Randomize;
try
sl.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
for i := 0 to sl.Count - 1 do begin
j := Random(sl.Count);
if i <> j then sl.Exchange(i,j);
end;
sl.SaveToFile('Result.txt');
finally
FreeAndNil(sl);
end;
end;
end;
```

Пыталась решить проблему вот так (**Но работает очень и очень медленно**):

```
var
    i, j, b: integer;
    ft, ft2: TextFile;
    s: string;
    sc: array of integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
 Randomize;
 AssignFile(ft, OpenDialog1.FileName);
 Reset(ft);
 i:= 0;

 // Подсчёт количества строк в файле
 while not Eof(ft) do
  begin
   Readln(ft);
   Inc(i);
  end;

 SetLength(sc, i);

 // Заполнение массива индексами строк
 for i := Low(sc) to High(sc) do sc[i]:= i;

 // Перемешивание индексов
 for i := High(sc) downto Low(sc) do
  begin
   b:= Random(i);
   j:= sc[b];
   sc[b]:= sc[i];
   sc[i]:= j;
  end;

 AssignFile(ft2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Random_STR.txt');
 Rewrite(ft2);

 for i := Low(sc) to High(sc) do
  begin

   // Имитация seek
   Reset(ft);
   for j:= 0 to sc[i] do Readln(ft, s);

   Writeln(ft2, s);
  end;

 CloseFile(ft);
 CloseFile(ft2);
end;
end;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перемешать строки в очень большом текстовом файле?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794851/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Comment: Татьяна, дайте пожалуйста вопросу нормальное название, и поясните, почему этот вопрос не является дубликатом прошлого.

Comment: Сделала, а почему вопрос не дубликат то ответ: Тут я привела еще два варианта. То что удалось сделать. Спасибо, справедливое замечание.

Comment: Татьяна, так стало гораздо лучше =) Уточните, насколько для вас важно перемешивать все строки по всему файлу, а не, например, в кусках по паре тысяч строк? Какова вообще цель этого перемешивания?

Comment: Если решаем вопрос "тормозов", то сначала надо точно понять, в чем причина тормозов. Прочитать файл 250мб с диска и записать обратно это примерно 10 секунд, на скорости 50мб в секунду (современные бюджетные HDD). Никакой алгоритм не позволит уменьшить это время, ведь все равно файл надо прочитать целиком и записать целиком, но в другом порядке.

Comment: `// Имитация seek
   Reset(ft);
   for j:= 0 to sc[i] do Readln(ft, s);` - вот от этого и тормоза, я описал в ответе как лучше сделать.

Comment: Kromster, Перемещать в кусках, можно по пару тысяч строк. А цель этого (работаю в офисе): генерация случайных отчетов в документах. То есть что бы каждый отчет был уникальный. Спасибо что помогаете.

Comment: @Татьяна какую версию Delphi вы используете?

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд есть несколько вариантов.

1. Грузите, например, эти строки в sqlite базу, и далее работаете уже с базой, например:

   `create table rows(id integer primary key, line text, number int)`
   и перемешиваете уже просто индексы и потом сохраняете в файл.
2. Считаете количество строчек в файле(ну и желательно сохранить смещение т.е. привязать номер строки к смещению в фалу), опять же перемешиваете индексы, и, потом по этим перемешенным индексам формируете новый файл (тут и пригодятся смещения, чтобы сразу получить по номеру строчки её смещение в файле и быстро прочитать и сохранить в новый)

Comment: Пыталась решить проблему другим способом. Работает но очень медленно, даже на файлах в 50 мегабайт. Внесла правки в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Идея у вас правильная, только в массив нужно записывать не индексы строк, а смещения этих строк в исходном файле, тогда не нужно будет перебирать весь файл, чтобы найти строку.

```
var
  i, j, b: integer;
  ft, ft2: TextFile;
  s: string;
  sc: array of integer;

begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    Randomize;

    AssignFile(ft, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(ft);

    i:= 0;

    SetLength(sc, 1000); // чтобы не перекладывать в памяти массив на каждой строчке

    // Подсчёт количества строк в файле
    while not Eof(ft) do
    begin
      sc[i] := FilePos(ft); // в массиве будут позиции начала строк

      Inc(i);

      if i >= Length(sc) then  // добавим еще 1000 элементов в массив, если не хватило
        SetLength(sc, Length(sc) + 1000);

      SeekEoln(ft);  // перейдем в конец строки
    end;

    SetLength(sc, i); // уберем лишние элементы массива

    // Перемешивание массива
    for i := High(sc) downto Low(sc) do
    begin
      b:= Random(i);
      j:= sc[b];
      sc[b]:= sc[i];
      sc[i]:= j;
    end;

    AssignFile(ft2, ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Random_STR.txt');
    Rewrite(ft2);

    for i := Low(sc) to High(sc) do
    begin
      Seek(ft, sc[i]);

      Readln(ft, s);

      Writeln(ft2, s);
    end;

    CloseFile(ft);
    CloseFile(ft2);
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPD:** Переписал на `FileStream`.

```
uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

type
  TLineRec = record
    Position: Cardinal;
    Size: integer;
  end;

var
  i, b: integer;
  TempLineRecord: TLineRec;
  ft: TextFile;
  s: string;
  sc: array of TLineRec;
  FilePosition: Cardinal;
  SourceFileStream: TFileStream;
  RandomFileStream: TFileStream;

const
  LINE_BREAK: Word = $0A0D;

if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
  Randomize;

  AssignFile(ft, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(ft);
  FilePosition := 0;

  i:= 0;

  SetLength(sc, 1000); // чтобы не перекладывать в памяти массив на каждой строчке

  // Подсчёт количества строк в файле
  while not Eof(ft) do
  begin
    sc[i].Position := FilePosition; // запоминаем позицию начала строки

    Readln(ft, s);  // читаем строку
    sc[i].Size := Length(s); // запоминаем длинну строки, предполагаем что файл в однобайтовой кодировке

    FilePosition := FilePosition + sc[i].Size + 2; // 2 байта на символы окончания строки

    Inc(i);

    if i >= Length(sc) then  // добавим еще 1000 элементов в массив, если не хватило
      SetLength(sc, Length(sc) + 1000);
  end;

  SetLength(sc, i); // уберем лишние элементы массива

  CloseFile(ft);

  // Перемешивание массива
  for i := High(sc) downto Low(sc) do
  begin
    b := Random(i); // почему бы не рандом от всего диапазона?
    TempLineRecord := sc[b];
    sc[b] := sc[i];
    sc[i] := TempLineRecord;
  end;

  SourceFileStream := TFileStream.Create(OpenDialog1.FileName, fmOpenRead);
  try
    RandomFileStream := TFileStream.Create(ExtractFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\Random_STR.txt', fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);
    try
      for i := Low(sc) to High(sc) do
      begin
        SourceFileStream.Position := sc[i].Position;

        // если sc[i].Size внезапно окажется = 0 (пустая строка), скопируется весь файл целиком!!!
        if sc[i].Size > 0 then
          RandomFileStream.CopyFrom(SourceFileStream, sc[i].Size);

        RandomFileStream.Write(LINE_BREAK, 2);  // допишем конец строки
      end;
    finally
      RandomFileStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    SourceFileStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку в строке:  Seek(ft, sc[i]); Не удается скомпилировать.  Очень Вам благодарна, что помогаете.

Comment: К сожалению, `Seek` не работает с текстовыми файлами. Я упустил этот момент в справке. В таком случае придется использовать `TFileStream` для произвольного чтения из файла.

Comment: А я бы вообще запоминал пары "смещение-длина", тогда можно отказаться от тормознутого readln и вообще всё делать через TFileStream.ReadBuffer();

Comment: Какой-то ответ "ни туда ни сюда". С одной стороны, описан алгоритм, с другой стороны, приведен нерабочий код. И это при том, что словами такой же алгоритм описан в ответе @Чад (под п.2). Так что тут надо или поправить код, или удалить ответ, как дублирующий.

Comment: @Татьяна я обновил ответ