# Варианты оптимизации кода Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Очень медленно работает такого плана код. Как можно ускорить? Или по другому переписать?

Читала про **потоки** информацию, но пока что, мне это - не под силу (опыта не очень много).

**Самая большая проблема:** Когда, в моем варианте, нужно обработать 25-30 запросов в 100 мегабайтном файле, то этот код очень медленно работает и нагружает систему.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var P, s1, s2, s3: TStringList;
     i: integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
 P := TStringList.Create;
 s1 := TStringList.Create;
 s2 := TStringList.Create;
 s3 := TStringList.Create;
 P.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
 for i := 0 to P.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if Pos(Edit1.text, P.Strings[i]) > 0 then s1.Add(P.Strings[i]);
    if Pos(Edit2.text, P.Strings[i]) > 0 then s2.Add(P.Strings[i]);
    if Pos(Edit3.text, P.Strings[i]) > 0 then s3.Add(P.Strings[i]);
  end;
 P.Free;
 s1.SaveToFile('1.txt');
 s2.SaveToFile('2.txt');
 s3.SaveToFile('3.txt');
 s1.Free;
 s2.Free;
 s3.Free;
end;
end;
end.
```

Comment: Это уже третья или четвертая, кажется, вариация одного и того же вопроса, что вы ранее задавали - как работать с большими текстовыми файлами

Comment: Kromster, Это последний вопрос этого плана, очень важен для меня. В дальнейшем буду задавать другие вопросы. Уже много что сделала сама, благодаря вашим подсказкам. Я это ценю.

Comment: @Татьяна Я согласен с Kromster. Я, лично, Вам [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803705/221228) показал как работать с большими файлами и что использовать TStringList когда нужна простая построчная обработка, глупо

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Только согласна. Не все еще освоила, но стараюсь теперь избежать подобных вопросов. Можете помочь в вашем коде(Вчера думала что все получиться,но не судьба,мне не легко все дается но я все же стараюсь и учу): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813056/Исправить-три-параметра-delphi-xe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно выкинуть вот это

```
P.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
```

и вообще **забыть** про стринглисты при работе с файлами. И читать и писать файл построчно.

Потом выкинуть использование функции `Pos`, потому, что она у Вас используется трижды и заменить на простой цикл по символам.

В коде это будет как-то так

```
procedure ProcessedFile(var F: TextFile; const Matching: array of string);
type
  // Информация об искомых строках
  StrInfo = record
    // В какой файл пишем результат
    F: TextFile;
    // Текущая позиция поиска
    Idx: Integer;
  end;
var
  LenArray: Integer;
  Str: string;
  InfoData: array of StrInfo;
  i: Integer;
  // Какой символ из считанной строки сравнивается
  CharIdx: Integer;
  // Сколько подстрок совпало
  MatchCnt: Integer;
  LenStr: Integer;
begin
  LenArray := Length(Matching);
  SetLength(InfoData, LenArray);
  // Используем это поле, чтобы узнать какие файлы удалось открыть
  // 0 - файл закрыт
  for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do
    InfoData[i].Idx := 0;
  try
    // Открываем все файлы на запись
    for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
      AssignFile(InfoData[i].F, IntToStr(i + 1) + '.txt');
      Rewrite(InfoData[i].F);
      // Файл открылся, 0 убрали
      InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
    end;

    while not Eof(F) do begin
      // Читаем следующую строку из файла
      Readln(F, Str);
      // Сравнение для всех подстрок начинаем с 1 символа
      for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do
        InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
      // Пока не нашли ни одной подстроки
      MatchCnt := 0;
      // Сравниваем каждый считанный символ с текущей позицией в искомой подстроке
      for CharIdx := 1 to Length(Str) do begin
        for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
          LenStr := Length(Matching[i]);
          // Если еще не нашли всю подстроку
          if InfoData[i].Idx <= LenStr then begin
            // Если текущий считанный символ совпадает с текущим символом в искомой подстроке
            if Str[CharIdx] = Matching[i, InfoData[i].Idx] then begin
              // Если дошли до конца подстроки, то совпали все символы
              if InfoData[i].Idx = LenStr then begin
                // Увеличиваем число совпадений
                Inc(MatchCnt);
                // Записываем считанную строку в нуужный файл
                Writeln(InfoData[i].F, Str);
              end else
                // Увеличиваем позицию
                Inc(InfoData[i].Idx);
            end else begin
              // Если текущий считанный символ НЕ совпадает с текущим символом в искомой подстроке
              // то начинаем поиск по этой подстроке сначала
              InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        // Если нашли ВСЕ подстроки, то дальше проверять символы не нужно
        if MatchCnt = LenArray then
          Break;  // прерываем текущую итерацию
      end;
    end;
  finally
    // Закрываем все открытые файлы
    for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
      // Если файл был открыт, то закрываем
      if InfoData[i].Idx <> 0 then
        CloseFile(InfoData[i].F);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TextFile;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    AssignFile(F, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(F);
    try
      ProcessedFile(F, [Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.Text]);
    finally
      CloseFile(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Anton Shchyrov очень сильно помогли. Только последний вопрос: Когда в коде пишу вот так InfoData[0].Str := '1'; то все работает. А когда пытаюсь подключить Edit то есть: InfoData[0].Str := edit1.text; то в коде подчеркивается edit1.text (и пишет undeclared identifier). Как исправить, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Татьяна Посмотрите, я изменил код

Comment: Теперь все работает. И еще забыла спросить. А можно еще добавить условие: Если Edit пустой то не создавать пустой файл. То есть не учитывать пустой edit. + Добавить условие - Соединить результаты в один файл. Если возможно то подскажите ?

Comment: @Татьяна Как соединить результаты? В каком порядке? Как строки шли в исходном файле, или вначале по одной подстроке, а потом по второй?

Comment: Соединить как шли в исходном файле. И еще я заметила такой момент: Когда ввожу один символ в Edit то программа сортирует. А когда слово ввожу то не сортирует. Это можно как то исправить что бы можно было и по словам сортировать строки (то ввожу слово, если слово есть в строке то строка записывается в файл) ?. Сразу извиняюсь что так много вопросов. Просто Вы, первый, кто в этом коде помогает. Уже месяц вожусь с этим кодом и вот благодаря Вам проблема решиться.

Comment: @Татьяна Если как шли в файле, то зачем Вы в исходном вопросе писали в разные файлы? Что такое `сортирует`? Программа ничего не сортирует. Давайте Вы отредактируете исходный вопрос и четко сформулируете, что нужно делать

Comment: Anton Shchyrov с этими вопросами я уже разобралась Благодаря Вам. Остался единственный как не только посимвольно обрабатывать текст а и по словам ? То есть что бы в edit можно было ввести слово и учитывать его. А то в таком варианте обрабатывается только по символьно.

Comment: @Татьяна Я исправил ошибку в коде. Теперь ищет по словам

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, Огромное спасибо вам, все работает. Вы меня выручили и очень сильно. Всегда буду Вам благодарна.