# Исправить три параметра Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Исправить три параметра в - коде.

**Добавить возможность:**

1. Если RadioButton1 активен значит результаты сохраняются в один файл.
2. Если RadioButton2 активен значит результаты сохраняются по разным файлам.
3. Если edit пустой то не создавать пустой файл при обработке.

Кому не сложно, помогите решить задачи. **Или хотя бы подскажите...**

```
procedure ProcessedFile(var F: TextFile; const Matching: array of string);
type
  // Информация об искомых строках
  StrInfo = record
    // В какой файл пишем результат
    F: TextFile;
    // Текущая позиция поиска
    Idx: Integer;
  end;
var
  LenArray: Integer;
  Str: string;
  InfoData: array of StrInfo;
  i: Integer;
  // Какой символ из считанной строки сравнивается
  CharIdx: Integer;
  // Сколько подстрок совпало
  MatchCnt: Integer;
  LenStr: Integer;
begin
  LenArray := Length(Matching);
  SetLength(InfoData, LenArray);
  // Используем это поле, чтобы узнать какие файлы удалось открыть
  // 0 - файл закрыт
  for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do
    InfoData[i].Idx := 0;
  try
    // Открываем все файлы на запись
    for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
      AssignFile(InfoData[i].F, IntToStr(i + 1) + '.txt');
      Rewrite(InfoData[i].F);
      // Файл открылся, 0 убрали
      InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
    end;

    while not Eof(F) do begin
      // Читаем следующую строку из файла
      Readln(F, Str);
      // Сравнение для всех подстрок начинаем с 1 символа
      for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do
        InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
      // Пока не нашли ни одной подстроки
      MatchCnt := 0;
      // Сравниваем каждый считанный символ с текущей позицией в искомой подстроке
      for CharIdx := 1 to Length(Str) do begin
        for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
          LenStr := Length(Matching[i]);
          // Если еще не нашли всю подстроку
          if InfoData[i].Idx <= LenStr then begin
            // Если текущий считанный символ совпадает с текущим символом в искомой подстроке
            if Str[CharIdx] = Matching[i, InfoData[i].Idx] then begin
              // Если дошли до конца подстроки, то совпали все символы
              if InfoData[i].Idx = LenStr then begin
                // Увеличиваем число совпадений
                Inc(MatchCnt);
                // Записываем считанную строку в нуужный файл
                Writeln(InfoData[i].F, Str);
              end else
                // Увеличиваем позицию
                Inc(InfoData[i].Idx);
            end else begin
              // Если текущий считанный символ НЕ совпадает с текущим символом в искомой подстроке
              // то начинаем поиск по этой подстроке сначала
              InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        // Если нашли ВСЕ подстроки, то дальше проверять символы не нужно
        if MatchCnt = LenArray then
          Break;  // прерываем текущую итерацию
      end;
    end;
  finally
    // Закрываем все открытые файлы
    for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
      // Если файл был открыт, то закрываем
      if InfoData[i].Idx <> 0 then
        CloseFile(InfoData[i].F);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: TextFile;
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
    AssignFile(F, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(F);
    try
      ProcessedFile(F, [Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.Text]);
    finally
      CloseFile(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что Вам нужно два чекбокса а не две радиокнопки? Что будет если они оба будут активны? Писать и в разные файлы и в один?

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov Если можно то две радиокнопки. Это будет правильней. Тут Вы отлично подметили.

Comment: @ Anton Shchyrov Писать в файлы: Если RadioButton1 то в разные, если RadioButton2 то в один.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Не подскажите как в вашем коде сделать условие: если файл с таким именем существует, то формируем новое имя файла.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, Сделала как сказали но ошибка error 102. Весь исправленный код - обновила в верху. Посмотрите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

Comment: Все, разобралась. Все сделала и работает.

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, А как в коде что в задании - обрабатывать текст без учета регистра. Сейчас учитывается регистр букв.

Comment: @Татьяна, пожалуйста, не изменяйте вопрос после того как на него ответили и вы приняли ответ - иначе получается, что ответ перестаёт собственно быть ответом на вопрос. Вместо этого вы можете задать новый вопрос и дать в нём ссылку на текущий, если требуется это)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Выбор разных файлов или одного решается просто.

   1. Передаем признак разности в процедуру

      ```
      procedure ProcessedFile(var F: TextFile; const Matching: array of string; DifferentFiles: Boolean);
      ```
   2. Объявляем общую файловую переменную

      ```
      var
        OutFile: TextFile;
        LenArray: Integer;
        ...........
      ```
   3. Инициализируем одну переменную или несколько

      ```
      // Открываем все файлы на запись
      if DifferentFiles then begin
        for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
          AssignFile(InfoData[i].F, IntToStr(i + 1) + '.txt');
          Rewrite(InfoData[i].F);
          // Файл открылся, 0 убрали
          InfoData[i].Idx := 1;
        end;
      end else begin
        AssignFile(OutFile, 'OutFile.txt');
        Rewrite(OutFile);
      end;
      ```
   4. Смотрим, куда будем писать

      ```
      // Записываем считанную строку в нужный файл
      if DifferentFiles then
        Writeln(InfoData[i].F, Str)
      else
        Writeln(OutFile, Str);
      ```
   5. Не забываем правильно закрыть файлы

      ```
      // Закрываем все открытые файлы
      if DifferentFiles then begin
        for i := 0 to LenArray - 1 do begin
          // Если файл был открыт, то закрываем
          if InfoData[i].Idx <> 0 then
            CloseFile(InfoData[i].F);
        end;
      end else
        CloseFile(OutFile);
      ```
   6. Ну и сам вызов

      ```
      ProcessedFile(F, [Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.Text], RadioButton2.Checked);
      ```
2. Проблему пустых эдитов можно решить двумя способами

   1. Не передавать пустые эдиты в процедуру

      ```
      function RemoveEmpty(const Strings: array of string): TArray<string>;
      var
        i: Integer;
        Count: Integer;
      begin
        Count := 0;
        for i := 0 to Length(Strings) - 1 do begin
          if Strings[i] <> '' then
            Inc(Count);
        end;
        SetLength(Result, Count);
        Count := 0;
        for i := 0 to Length(Strings) - 1 do begin
          if Strings[i] <> '' then begin
            Result[Count] := Strings[i];
            Inc(Count);
          end;
        end;
      end;

      procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      var
        F: TextFile;
      begin
        if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
          AssignFile(F, OpenDialog1.FileName);
          Reset(F);
          try
            ProcessedFile(F, RemoveEmpty([Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text, Edit3.Text]));
          finally
            CloseFile(F);
          end;
        end;
      end;
      ```
   2. Отфильтровать пустые строки в самой процедуре

      ```
      procedure ProcessedFile(var F: TextFile; const Matching: array of string; DifferentFiles: Boolean);
      var
        LocalMatching: TArray<string>;
        LenArray: Integer;
        ...................
      begin
        LocalMatching := RemoveEmpty(Matching);
        if Length(LocalMatching) = 0 then
          Exit;
      ```

Comment: Спасибо все работает. Только вот Отфильтровать пустые строки (вариант номер 2) пишет undeclared identifier, в LocalMatching := RemoveEmpty(Matching); Неизвестный идентификатор. В чем может быть проблема ?

Comment: @Татьяна Я надеюсь, что Вы объявили эту функцию?

Comment: Добавила отредактированный код в вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Да функцию добавила.

Comment: @Татьяна И Вы ее добавили **перед** тем местом, где она вызывается?

Comment: А вот тут запуталась. Не могу понять как правильно....

Comment: @Татьяна RemoveEmpty, ProcessedFile, Button1Click

Comment: Сделала. Посмотрите код выше, отредактировала вопрос. А теперь вот эту фразу выделяет красным: function RemoveEmpty(const Strings: array of string): array of string;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75911/discussion-between--and-anton-shchyrov).

Comment: Давайте, я в чате.

Comment: Не подскажите как в вашем коде сделать условие: если файл с таким именем существует, то формируем новое имя файла.

Comment: @Татьяна Перед `AssignFile(InfoData[i].F, IntToStr(i + 1) + '.txt');` добавить `if FileExists(IntToStr(i + 1) + '.txt') then ...`

Comment: Сделала как сказали но ошибка error 102. Весь исправленный код - обновила в верху. Посмотрите пожалуйста что я делаю не так.

Comment: Все, разобралась. Все сделала и работает.

Comment: А как в коде что в задании - обрабатывать текст без учета регистра. Сейчас учитывается регистр букв.

Comment: По поводу тревоги об изменений вопроса - откатите его, пожалуйста, к тому состоянию на который был дан ваш ответ, а то нам сложно разобраться до какой правки откатывать. А мы попросим @Татьяна не исправлять вопрос после принятия ответа на него и задавать новый отдельный вопрос, если после решения текущего появляются новые вопросы)